# Is the DOF for a robot mechanism invariant if it is not in a different configuration?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics, linkage

I understand that if the robot is reconfigured, it can potentially change the DOF, but would the degrees of freedom for the robot also change if specific links were fixed and as such specific joints were not allowed to move?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it would change.

Say you have an arm that can both rotate and extend or retract.

Say it has a joint articulation with a range of rotation about X, Y, Z axis and at the same time can elongate telescopically. Hence 4 DOF. If any of them is constrained or locked by either robot or by command the degree of freedom is one less.